# cannot connect to X server when running a python file on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying for the first time to run a python file from google colab.
I uploaded the file along with the folders required to do so to my drive (for reference, I am trying to run this project https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP)
Then, I am mounting the files to my drive, changing the directory to the map project and running the file as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/map"
!python main.py
```

But I keep getting : cannot connect to X server . Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577083/cannot-connect-to-x-server-google-colab Looks like the code is trying to use graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and let me know if you still have problems:

```
# Import PyDrive and associated libraries.
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth, drive
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
GoogleDrive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Mount Google Drive for file import
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/map"
!python main.py
```