# Cannot connect to X server in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, yolo, xserver

I have tried running this python file: [detectvideo_counter.py](https://github.com/molimat/YOLOv4-Counter-in-TF/blob/master/detectvideo_counter.py)

However, the python file does not completely run and gives this output:

```
: cannot connect to X server
```

I have tried the suggestions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577083/cannot-connect-to-x-server-google-colab)

However, I still had no luck.

Could you please tell me how to solve this (other than running it locally)?

Comment: I have also tried doing it locally. A window automatically shows up for you to draw a line.

Results are here: https://github.com/molimat/YOLOv4-Counter-in-TF/issues/5#issuecomment-745242554

Comment: It's not possible to run in Colab because it opens a separate window. I tried running it locally and it worked when I used Tensorflow 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer here for the benefit of the community, since the user has already solved the issue.

[This](https://github.com/molimat/YOLOv4-Counter-in-TF/blob/master/detectvideo_counter.py) program can be run locally by changing the `Tensorflow` version to `2.2.0`.
However, it is not possible to run this on colab due to one of the reasons listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577083/cannot-connect-to-x-server-google-colab) post.
You can find the error details from this GitHub [link](https://github.com/molimat/YOLOv4-Counter-in-TF/issues/5#issuecomment-745242554).